# Images in Attachments are not showing up in Experience site

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I created customer community and I am using lightning aura component to display the records along with the pictures.
I even checked the **Let customer users access notes and attachments** checkbox from the settings but still I am nota able to see the attachments.

Please help me or let me know any other way around.

**I can not use the static resource as the attachments will behave like a profile picture. Thus, they have to be dynamic.**

```
<lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
                        <img src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0685f000001Rj9sAAC" alternativeText="John Smith" size = "100"/>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
```

[image: Site image]

Comment: You can create document folder and add external image. Or add static resources publicly available. Where you are attaching the items they are controlled by parent record visibility.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit?
I want the images to be dynamic like if person 'A' is being queried the image of that person should be shown on page.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question and update with a mock or something it's not what I understood.  What records you want to show. In your console you must be getting some error can you access your image path by coping in browser